# Is this absolute timeline correct?

Tags: calendar

I always thought it put things into perspective if, instead of the Gregorian Calendar, we had a kind of "absolute" timeline, going all the way back to the big bang, as well as we can define it as of today, in 2012.

Of course, this would be ridiculously impractical (today's date would be something like year 13,749,999,999.) I only mean this as a learning tool, and to point out just how relatively few years written history has been around.

My question is, do you agree that this would be a helpful learning tool for students to comprehend a kind of birds-eye-view of the timeline?

Here's an example of what I'm talking about.  The column on the left would be the year the event on the right-hand column occured:

```
 1  The Big Bang
 9,150,000,000  Earth forms
 10,150,000,000     simple cells
 10,350,000,000     photosynthesis
 11,750,000,000     complex cells
 12,750,000,000     multicellular life
 13,150,000,000     animals
 13,250,000,000     fish
 13,275,000,000     land plants
 13,350,000,000     insects and seeds
 13,390,000,000     amphibians
 13,450,000,000     reptiles
 13,550,000,000     mammals
 13,600,000,000     birds
 13,620,000,000     flowers
 13,685,000,000     dinosaurs die out
 13,747,500,000     genus Homo appears
 13,749,800,000     modern humans appear
 13,749,975,000     Neanderthals disappear
 13,749,994,488     writing begins
 13,749,995,000     civilization begins along the Euphrates River in Mesopotamia, along the Nile, along the Indus River
 13,749,995,988     recorded history (writing down history) HISTORY begins
 13,749,997,988     christ is born
 13,749,999,999     today
```

Really puts things into perspective, doesn't it? Do you agree or do you think this would just be confusing to kids? Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Sorry, but this question can't really be answered objectively, so I have to close it. Any question that is likely to solicit opinion, discussion, or debate is not appropriate for this site. Please read through our FAQ to get a better idea of the kind of questions that are accpetable.

Comment: Maybe I could rephrase it - I think you're right. Can I ask if the dates I have listed are correct?

Comment: @Steven Drennon he asks for whether he made mistakes. This can be answered.

Comment: I see two mistakes so far: Big Bang should be 0. Dinosaurs never died out.

Comment: "Do you agree or do you think this would just be confusing to kids?" Questions like this are most likely to be answered with opinions and discussions. One person may say yes while another says no and a third says maybe. Sorry, "but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion", which is straight from the guidelines. I don't see it as a good fit.